# Old Public IP has past owners DNS name

Tags: dns, ip, ipv4

I have a new IPv4 address and every DNS Resolver site tells me that my DNS name is toponscapital.com.

What can I do to at least change this?

Comment: toponscapital.com does not resolve, from my system. I do not think it has anything to do with DNS

Comment: It absolutely has to do with DNS, however it uses a special zone "in-addr.arpa" and weird and butchered syntax to do things in reverse.

Answer (score 3):

Talk to whoever assigned the IPv4 address to you. They should be able to change the DNS to whatever you want it to be or explain to you how to do so.

Comment: I did exactly this and it has now been sorted. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

Contact your ISP and ask them how to change/update the reverse DNS.  Usually they'll have to do it for you.